# Building old latex file - Forgot series of commands, still got old .log file

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, makeindex

So I have to make some editions to an old 200 pages latex file which has tikz, figures, bibliography, indexes, etc. Since the last time I compiled it, I changed the build commands to compile more simple documents.

I totally forgot the series of commands I used to build this old big file. Is it possible to find the previously  employed series of commands by taking a look into the .log or maybe .aux file?

Comment: One of the most important pieces of information should be visible at the start of the `.log` file: The engine (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX) and the format (LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). For the rest (index commands, bibliography commands, ...) things are trickier, I don't doubt that you can extract quite some info from the `.log` file and from the `.tex`, but it is probably very context dependent what exactly you need to look for and I can imagine there are cases where it is not strictly speaking possible to reconstruct the exact compilation sequence.

Comment: Is something not working if you use `pdflatex` five times, then the index and bibliography, and then `pdflatex` another five times?

Comment: @moewe the top of the log file says "This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.3.25)" and I think I used xelatex as the compiler... does that make sense?

Comment: @Teepeemm I also have glossaries and I am using xelatex as the compiler (I think). Is the build structure still the same? i.e. "xelatex xelatex xelatex xelatex xelatex makeindex biber makeglossaries xelatex xelatex xelatex xelatex xelatex" ?

Comment: It's worth a shot (and definitely faster than the hour you've waited for this to get noticed).  The 10 total times is probably overkill, but it can't hurt.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, if you find `preloaded format=xelatex` you used `xelatex` to compile. Now you just have to find out what other helper tools you need to run in which order. For most documents it is OK to run Biber (bibliography), `makeindex` (index), `makeglossaries` (glossary) without a XeLaTeX call in between, but in some special cases (you turned on citation indexing or you cite something in an index/glossary entry), you may need a XeLaTeX run between them. ...

Comment: ... If I wanted to be absolutely sure, I'd probably run XeLaTeX, `makeglossaries`, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX, `makeindex`, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX. The good thing is that many packages show warnings in the `.log` file if you need to re-run a certain program, so that should be able to give you a hint as to what to do in many instances.